# How do I get the blue location dot to appear in my Android application?

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to Android programming and I'm a bit stuck. I have a map set up and now I want to add the blue flashing dot to the application to show where the user is on the map.

How do I do this?

Comment: The blue dot is the Current Location shown after the user clicks the My Location button in the upper right part of the map.  You can show a Marker at the current location, as is described in the tutorial you linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try implementing this code, hope this works fine for you.

```
 private GoogleMap mMap;

    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Hello world")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

If it does not work for you, try keep in touch with me.

Comment: won't this set the marker to 0,0 instead of the user's current location?

Comment: No you don't. This is just your current or destination latitude and longitude where the location have been fetched.

Comment: no this isn't working. i have been following a tutorial which uses similar code to the one you provided to demonstrate how to add a marker, but it gets latitude and longitude data from location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude(). You can see the tutorial at: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android

Comment: First you have to set your current location and when you fetched it perfectly, add the same marker. Google has provided the blue marker instead you can put your design. The same I have implemented was working fine.

Comment: Hey. I have implemented the above code, you can simple check and let me know in case if any query has to be fulfill.